# classification using logistic regression on stock data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, finance

I have made a model which is supposed to classify the trend of a stock index as an "up day" (=1) or a "no change"/"down day"(=0), where I have coded an "up day" as when the percent change for the index today is > 0. The model has been trained and validated on data where I know if the index has been a 1 or a 0.

However, I want to apply my model to days where I don't know the direction of today's market. How would I go about solving this? Any advice is much appreciated :) Also, first question on this forum (have been a reader for some time, finally took the step right? :))

---

My model looks like the following:

direction ~ Bo+B1x1+...+B19x19, where direction = 1 if index > 0, 0 otherwise

B1 to B5 are lagged variables of the index I want to predict and the rest is variables with closing time before or after the index of interest.

Since I don't know the direction of the index today, I don't have anything to predict(?)

Comment: Why would you build this model when you can model actual returns? There's so much more information in returns than a 0,1 dependent variable!

Comment: How did you train your model? If your independent variables are observed at time  t-1 (or t-k for k>=1) and you are predicting the direction of the index at time t, then you merely need to plug in yesterday's (or previous days) values of your independent variables into your model to obtain the predicted index movement today.

Comment: I trained it with five lagged variables of the index to be predicted and indexes for markets which close in the early morning and late evening relative to my time zone, so I guess in some sense they could also be lagged variables (?) even though they don't fit the formal definition. My problem seem to be that when I don't know the outcome of today, I don't have any variable to predict?

Comment: Although I can see a point to creating such a model for characterizing market changes *post hoc,* I believe that most people--whose information is routinely limited to events in the past--think models of asset prices that require knowledge of the future are useless.

Comment: @whuber   "Useless" is a strong word. "Weakly predictive" is probably the better choice. As in Edward Thorp's book *Beat the Dealer* about the first Vegas card counter, if you can get a 3-4% edge (or better) over the house, you're in the money.

Comment: @DJohnson "Useless" is correct, because nobody has future information.  *If you have to wait until after the event you want to predict in order to predict it,* then the model truly is useless for prediction.

Comment: @whuber  We're going to have to agree to disagree on this one. Your position is equivalent to Fama's strong, efficient market hypothesis -- which is controversial. While you are correct in saying that "nobody has future information," this is not the same thing as saying that market moves are totally random. In other words, *alpha* exists and it is possible to beat a random selection of assets, if only by a few basis points. If your assumptions were correct then there would be no arbitrage and no one would make any money.

Comment: @DJohnson I don't think we're disagreeing: I think we must be referring to totally different things.  My understanding is that this model is something of the form "Tomorrow's price is predicted to equal today's price plus the change from tomorrow to the day after tomorrow."  That could have great value in *characterizing* price changes after the fact, but nobody without a time machine could ever make a useful prediction with it.

Comment: @whuber  Is the core issue one of market randomness? It would appear that it is. Correct me if this is a mischaracterization of your views but you seem to think that the randomness in asset prices is such that it renders any and all efforts at prediction useless. This may be a theoretically justified view, but it is not the reality of price movements and changes. The reality is that these moves are *weakly predictable*.

Comment: @DJ Yes, that mischaracterizes what I have been attempting to communicate.  *Any model that requires tomorrow's data in order to predict what happens tomorrow is useless.*  That is a statement only about time's arrow, not about randomness, modeling, or stocks.

Answer (score 1):

Fit the model to all of your training data, then use it to make predictions for the unlabeled cases. Nothing more specific can be said than that without knowing what sort of model you're using, what programming language you're using, etc.

Comment: I'm using a logistic regression to classify and I'm in R.

Comment: Try `predict(model, newdata, type = "response")`.